# Livebroadcast does not bind to liveStream, how can I bind it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

If I use the following code, I get a valid response (no errors) back from the Youtube API.
Only the stream does not seem to bind.

```
def bind_broadcast_to_stream(broadcast_id, livestream_id)
  data = { empty: "string" }
  begin
    request = RestClient.post(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/bind?key=#{GOOGLE_API_KEY}&part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&id=#{broadcast_id}&stream_id=#{livestream_id}",
      data.to_json,
      content_type: :json,
      accept: :json,
      authorization: "Bearer #{self.get_token}"
    )
    return JSON.parse(request)
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => err
    return err.response.body
  end
end
```

I can bind it manual by going to the Youtube studio, but then I get a different stream key.
After that (and streaming on of course) I can go live with the following code:

```
def set_broadcast_status(broadcast_id, status)
  data = { empty: "string" }
  begin
    request = RestClient.post(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?key=#{GOOGLE_API_KEY}&part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&alt=json&id=#{broadcast_id}&broadcastStatus=#{status}",
      data.to_json,
      content_type: :json,
      accept: :json,
      authorization: "Bearer #{self.get_token}"
    )
    return JSON.parse(request)
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => err
    return err.response.body
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was adding a response body..

According to the Youtube API manual (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind):
Do not provide a request body when calling this method.

```
def bind_broadcast(broadcast_id, livestream_id)
  begin
    request = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/bind",
      headers: {
        params: { key: GOOGLE_API_KEY, part: "id,snippet,contentDetails,status", id: broadcast_id, streamId: livestream_id, alt: 'json' },
        content_type: :json,
        accept: :json,
        authorization: "Bearer #{self.get_token}"
      }
    )
    return JSON.parse(request)
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => err
    return err.response.body
  end
end
```